# Searching tree-like data

Tags: javascript, search, tree

I have a tree-like structure in which I need to search data. For example if I have the following object:

```
{
  rowData: 32,
  children: {
    rowData: 33,
    children: {
      rowData: 2,
      children: {
        rowData: 55,
      },
    },
  },
}
```

If I search for "2" I would like to end up with this:

```
{
  rowData: 32,
  children: {
    rowData: 33,
    children: {
      rowData: 2
    },
  },
}
```

Do you have any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: what goes wrong?

Comment: what is main objective?

Comment: can you show your code?